# set dynamic value css animation stroke-dashoffset

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation

I am trying to bind the stroke-dashoffset from Javascript.
i want to replace the 20s with the variable this.waittime.
how to do it?

```
 this.waitime = 20;
value[i].style.transition = value[i].style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 20s ease-in-out';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `this.waitime` is just a variable you can concat strings and this variable together to make your desired string as follows,

```
this.waitime = 20;
value[i].style.transition = value[i].style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset ' + this.waitime + 's ease-in-out';
```

Comment: Could you add some informations about this answer please.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing this is by using template strings.
Basically those let you write the variable directly into the given string, and replace it with whatever value it has at the given time.
Template strings start and end with backticks, see this example:

```
this.waitime = 20;
value[i].style.transition = value[i].style.WebkitTransition = `stroke-dashoffset ${this.waitime}s ease-in-out`;
```